# Index error on splitting arrays

Tags: python

I have the following array(in python):

```
arr= ['\n', ' a#B\n', ' c#D\n']
```

Now I an trying to split on '#' for which I am writing the code given below:

```
 for i in arr:
 g=i.split("#")[1]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 g=i.split("#")[1]
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not getting why am I getting the error. Can someone be kind enough to help rectify it.

Comment: Incidentally, it's called a `list`, not an "array" in python.

Comment: do you want to keep the trailing `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the first element of your list, `'\n'` is assigned to `i` it does not contain `"#"`, so the result list is only one element long, not two.  Attempting to retrieve index `1` fails, but index `0` would be present.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained why you're getting that exception. Here's an idea for a different approach that may be useful to you.

Starting with Python 2.5, string objects grew a new `partition` method:

`str.partition(sep)`

> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before  the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.

```
>>> arr= ['\n', ' a#B\n', ' c#D\n'] 
>>> for s in arr:
...     print s.partition('#')
... 
('\n', '', '')
(' a', '#', 'B\n')
(' c', '#', 'D\n')
```

You can pull the string apart without encountering an excpetion whether the separator is found or not.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because the first split results in a list that contains only 1 element `['\n']`, so the index value of `[1]` is out of bounds.

See:

```
for i in arr:
   g = i.split("#")
   print g
```

output:

```
['\n']
[' a', 'B\n']
[' c', 'D\n']
```

One quick way to fix it would be:

```
[i.split('#')[1] for i in arr if len(i.split('#')) > 1]
```

though it contains two calls to `split()`.

The one below is a bit more verbose, but only calls `split()` once.

```
for i in arr:
    g = i.split('#')
    if len(g) > 1:
       g = g[1]
```

As @kindall suggests below in the comments, the use of `partition()` is an alternative to `split()` here too.

Comment: Better way: use `partition()` instead of `split()`. It always returns three elements and you can just get the last; it'll be blank if the separator doesn't exist.

Comment: @kindall partition instead of the split()?

Answer (score 0):

The first element in your array that you iterate through has no hash `#` so when you call split on it, it returns only 1 item in the list as in `['\n']` so when you try to access the second item by `[1]` it can't find it giving you the error.

Remember, in Python indexing starts at 0, not 1.